# Multiple buttons using same function

Tags: javascript

I have multiple buttons I would like to increment a value in different corresponding inputs. I am able to get all the buttons working but they only effect the first input. I realize I can write out three different functions for each button but I know there is a way to utilize one function.  Thank you for any help in advance!

Here is code for reference:

```js
let submit = document.querySelectorAll(".submit");
let num = document.querySelector(".num");

submit.forEach((btn)=>{
  btn.addEventListener("click", increment);
});

let value = 0;

function increment(){
  value +=1;
  num.value = value;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="main">

    <button class="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="withinDiv"><input type="number" class="num" value="0"></input>     </div>

    <button class="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="withinDiv"><input type="number" class="num" value="0"></input>     </div>

    <button class="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="withinDiv"><input type="number" class="num" value="0"></input>     </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You should have a `event` variable coming in your `increment()` function. This event has a `target` field. Try to set an ID per button and identify the target with this ID.

Comment: select the next sibling

Comment: And `<input/>` tags are self-closing, `<input></input>` is not valid HTML

Answer (score 2):

Select the [next sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) and select the input.

```js
const submit = document.querySelectorAll(".submit");

submit.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", increment);
});

function increment() {
  const inp = this.nextElementSibling.querySelector("input");
  inp.value = Number(inp.value) + 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="main">

    <button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="withinDiv"><input type="number" class="num" value="0"> </div>

    <button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="withinDiv"><input type="number" class="num" value="0"> </div>


    <button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="withinDiv"><input type="number" class="num" value="0"> </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This worked, I need to familiarize myself with children and siblings and this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

That's how i would do it - basically in your "`submit`" buttons you create attribute (in this case "`for`" (see EDIT)) that will point to `id` of `input` to be incremented. This gives you full flexibility, no matter what html you have.

**EDIT**

Better use custom attribute, for example `data-for`, button doesn't have `for` attribute, as pointed in the comments below

```js
let submit = document.querySelectorAll(".submit");


submit.forEach((btn)=>{
  btn.addEventListener("click", increment);
});



function increment(ev){
  let targetInputId = ev.target.getAttribute("data-for");
  let targetInput = document.getElementById(targetInputId);
  
  targetInput.value = parseInt(targetInput.value) + 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="main">

    <button data-for="num1" class="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="withinDiv"><input id="num1" type="number" class="num" value="0"></input>     </div>

    <button data-for="num2" class="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="withinDiv"><input id="num2" type="number" class="num" value="0"></input>     </div>

    <button data-for="num3" class="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="withinDiv"><input id="num3" type="number" class="num" value="0"></input>     </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: [Buttons don't have a `for` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Attributes), but you can use a custom `data-foobar` _(replace `foobar` with a more meaningful name)_

Comment: They don't have, yet you still can use it, and yes, i would do "data-for" actually, just, you know, typed right from them head - anyway "just for example"

Comment: Just because you _can_, does not mean you _should_ write or advise people to write invalid HTML

Comment: Ok, let me fix that

Comment: Thank you guys for clearing things up for me. Seems like learning is never ending. Especially, when looking at trying to keep code practical.

Comment: I see I was beat to it :) I do believe this is a better solution as it does not break if more siblings are added to the HTML.